# Live Streaming a Video File

Tags: php, video-streaming

I have to create a Theater effect on a website such that a Video needs to be streamed so that all the users of the website can see it simultaneously.

I have checked Ustream, Livstream etc but they allow my webcam to be streamed online.
The functionality I need is similar to how we see a Cricket/Soccer Match online where all the users see the same clip. The only difference is that I already have a video that needs to be streamed.

Please help.

Comment: Upload video in your server -> Use HTML5 video player -> WebSocket (like Node.js to send current times or use Pusher.com)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it with PHP because you can't handle multiple HTTP request in a PHP script. However, you can do it easily with node.js. You can first store each user's HTTP request and time in an array, then you find out the first one that watch the video. Calculate the video's elapsed time and slice the video. Finally send the video back to the current client.

**Another solution (If you decided to use node.js)**

Simulate the playing of the video on the server side by using `setTimeout` when the first user request the video. Then when other users request the video you slice it and send it to the client. Because you simulate the playing on the server side, you can then no need to calculate the elapsed time of the video.

The slicing of the video can be done with FFMpeg easily.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it will be too much work to calculate the remaining time for every user that comes in. This would also require that I slice the video . If we have somehow 1 video playing for all users similar to how streaming is, we can then get it done.

Comment: I have posted another solution, check it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. FFMpeg seems to be a command line tool and I am not sure if we can use it when the video is being played. I understand the Simulation however do you have any other way to approach it? Thanks

Comment: I was able to get it working with javascript setTimeout . Once the page loads, I am sending request to the server every second and storing the elapsed time in database. This request also returns the current status of Video (played/paused/stopped) and time interval passed. When a new user arrive, I get the elapsed time and seek the video to that time. This way it works for all the users simultaneously.  However somehow the requests stop going after say 50 odd requests. When I check the request through Firebug, the request has turned 'red' which I believe is a Timeout issue. Please confirm

Comment: @Kunal981 If you're using node.js you can just store the state and the elapsed time in a variable. That way it'll work much faster. If not, you can consider storing the progress information to a file or in shared memory instead of a database to reduce latency.